# FFMpeg: how to play 2 flv's next to each other in 1 flv

Tags: video, ffmpeg, flv

I have two FLV files and I want to create 1 FLV file where both FLV are displayed next to each other.

For example: 2 people recorded themselves with a webcam. I want to create 1 FLV where I see the first user and the second user next to each other.

Is this possible with FFMpeg?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use [avisynth](http://avisynth.org/mediawiki/Main_Page), see this thread http://forum.doom9.org/archive/index.php/t-121000.html

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.flv -s 400x200 -vf "movie=3200000:flv:2.flv, scale=200:200, setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, pad=400:200:200:0, [T1] overlay=0:0 [out]; [in] scale=200:200, setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [T1]" out.flv
```